# How to create logout when expires token

Tags: reactjs, redux

could someone help me to resolve this problem? 
I don't know how to implement expired session to my react app.

I have json data with `expires_in: 86400` what I need to do to implement this to my app, when expired to logout user.

I using react.JS and redux.

Action:

```
export const signin = obj => {
  return dispatch => {
    let data = {
      method: "post",
      url: "/oauth/token",
      data: {
        grant_type: "password",
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
        username: obj.email,
        password: obj.password
      }
    };
    return API(data)
      .then(res => {
        window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access_token);
        console.log('uuuuuuuuuu', res)
        dispatch({
          type: AUTH.LOGGED_IN,
          payload: {
            access_token: res.data.access_token,
            expired_in: res.data.expires_in
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw err;
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: you can use `setInterval` to schedule an action with the interval as the value in `expires_in`. Once the interval is reached, you can clear the interval and execute your log out action. Let me know if you need an example for that. I m assuming that `expires_in` is the relative time value for which the token is valid not the absolute time.

Comment: Please show me some example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this using `setTimeout` function to trigger your logout functionality. The below code is on the assumption that `expires_in` is the relative time not the absolute time.

```
    window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access_token);
    setTimeout(logoutFunction, response.data.expires_in)
    console.log('uuuuuuuuuu', res)
    dispatch({
      type: AUTH.LOGGED_IN,
      payload: {
        access_token: res.data.access_token,
        expired_in: res.data.expires_in
      }
    });
```

and your `logoutFunction` will look something like this:

```
function logOutFunction() {
   window.localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
   // your redux dispatch and probably a redirection logic to go to a proper UX page
}
```

I mistakenly said in comments to use `setInterval`. I assume this will be a one time execution, `setTimeout` is better to use.

Answer (score 0):

From your code I found. you have used  `window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access_token);` 
But you actually need a cookie there and set the expire time from the response. Then you have to check is that the cookie existence in the parent component. if it, not exist (expired) you can redirect to the login page.

For force logout, you can simply make the cookie expire. ;)

Comment: I understand that, do you have some example of code?

Comment: If you are storing jwt tokens in localStorage, there’s no need to use cookies.

Comment: Use the following code. 
cookies.set('access_token', res.data.access_token, { path: '/', maxAge: res.data.expires_in});

instead of
window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", res.data.access_token);

Make sure you have imported Cookies from 'universal-cookie' package.

Comment: You must need cookie if you want that access_token has to be expired in 86400 sec. Because you can't set the expire time to localStorage.

Comment: I got this now
https://imgur.com/a/ej9GkHY

So, what I need to do next. 
I mean, if token expired page will be redirected automatically or  I need to do something more?
Also, I need to remove some things from local storage

Comment: It won't redirect automatically. you have to check in the parent constructor or globally. like this

constructor(props){
      super(props);
      let jwt = cookies.get('access_token') || '';
      if(jwt === ''){
        props.history.push('/pages/login');  //redirect to login page
      }
}

Comment: Of course you can do it with localStorage. Once the response arrives, you store the current time + the expiration time. That gives you when does the token expire into localStorage, which you can check against the current time whenever you want to use the token.

Comment: @Prabusamvel could you please explain me why I need to use in constructor here? Or I can put this code to another place?

Comment: Of course, you can put the code globally somewhere. In this case for a single component, I used the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t store the time left to expire, but the current time + the time left. Otherwise you can’t know when this happened.

Comment: Do you have some example of what I need to do? :)

Comment: Same place you store the access_token to localStorage, just store the expires_in + new Date().getTime(). Same for the payload to redux. Then you can either check redux against new Date().getTime() every time you want to use the token, or use a setTimeout to schedule a refresh before it expires. Also, when your app is loaded, you have to put it back to redux (and the timeout if you used it) from what's stored in localStorage.